# trying to avoid duplicates using inner joins (mysql)

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates, inner-join, distinct

```
SELECT T.instnum, T.batchnum, T.recdate, 
       T.operator, T.booknum, T.bpagenum, 
       T.epagenum, T.nonstandarddoc, 
       E.returntoname, S.receivedfrom 
FROM TBL_Transactions T
inner join TBL_TransEfile S on S.instnum = T.instnum
inner join EFL_Trans E on E.batchnum = S.mosbatchnum
where T.nonstandarddoc = 'y' 
  and T.`year` = '2017' 
  and T.efiledocument = 'y' 
order by instnum asc
```

When i ran this query it does display the information i need but since i am pulling the information from 2 tables it seems that is not excluding the duplicates, i have tried distinct which does lower the amount of entries but not to the real one, the instrument number (instnum) is what dictates the results and if there was a way to make the tables avoid duplicates by using the instnum as a guide would be perfect

example of a result:

```
'2017007122', 1001071, '20170208', 'JSCHULTZ', '7902', 1226, 1230, 'Y', '', 'simplifile'
'2017007122', 1001071, '20170208', 'JSCHULTZ', '7902', 1226, 1230, 'Y', 'Orion Financial Group, Inc.', 'simplifile'
```

as you can see it is returning the same information except for a vendor name, if we can make the query avoid the duplicates that would be great, thanks in advance for anyone's help.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can use the `Group By` to avoid the duplicates.

Comment: Please tell us what result you need and explain the logic. Because right now they are two different records and we dont know which one is the correct.

Comment: @RikenShah Thank you, that worked

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Being the first time i am putting anything here i apologize for not being clear, but i will be in the future if another questions comes up

Comment: @Epilef Because i've read use GROUP BY to avoid duplicates... read this https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, just *say* you don't want duplicates, via DISTINCT. Using GROUP BY when you don't need groups is just unclear. If you don't get distinct rows by asking for them them your join is wrong. Act on [mcve]. You need to describe what rows you want output given input. If you solved your problem, please post an answer & accept it to tell people.